# conflict font and icons in the angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to use the custom font in all of the pages of the website and right now I use this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: IRANSans;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('./assets/fonts/iran-sans/eot/IRANSansWeb.eot');
  src: url('./assets/fonts/iran-sans/eot/IRANSansWeb.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-8 */
  url('./assets/fonts/iran-sans/woff2/IRANSansWeb.woff2') format('woff2'), /* FF39+,Chrome36+, Opera24+*/
  url('./assets/fonts/iran-sans/woff/IRANSansWeb.woff') format('woff'), /* FF3.6+, IE9, Chrome6+, Saf5.1+*/
  url('./assets/fonts/iran-sans/ttf/IRANSansWeb.ttf') format('truetype');
}


* {
  font-family: IRANSans !important;
}
```

I also use the Angular Material fonts like this :

```
    <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Vex - Angular 9+ Material Design Admin Template</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
  <link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

When I need to show the icons I get this message:

[image]

But when I remove this line it displays the icons properly:

```
* {
   font-family: IRANSans !important;
  }
```

What's the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Because the CSS selector you're using (the [universal CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors)) selects _all_ elements of any type and as such may override whatever CSS styles you have specified before. I suggest you should read up on how to specify a custom typography in the documentation: https://material.angular.io/guide/typography

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The above answer is correct: * means all. 
What you can do: You can try to set the iran font for all but not the icons.

please try this selector

```
*:not(.material-icons) { font-family: IRANSans !important; }
```

instead of   *